# shift+insert on mac keyboard?

Tags: mac

How to do <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> on a mac keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

What behaviour would you expect? Isn't that like Paste (Ctrl+V on Windows, hence Command-V on a Mac?)

See also Apple's [Mac tips for Windows switchers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204216).

Comment: No, it is not like Paste when you are running a VM on Mac and try to Shift-Insert into a Linux terminal.

Comment: @someuser, for future visitors, please post an answer if you figured out a way to send that keystroke? (In Windows, Shift+Enter often _is_ Paste.)

Comment: This doesn't, in any way answer to OPs question.

The behavior he expects is "to send a Shift-Insert keystroke"!  It's a very valid question.  It is why I found this page.

It is just a passive aggressive insult.

Comment: @Wayne I re-read my answer and I disagree. In Mac software Shift+Insert is not a common thing. But on, e.g., Windows the IBM-standard Shift+Insert worked for pasting [even before it also introduced Ctrl+V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste#Popularization). So even if others may truly need Shift+Insert, I still feel that pasting may very well be what readers may be looking for. Also, I've no idea why anyone would want to read any "passive aggressive insult" in my answer. (But hat tip for explaining the downvote. And upvote for yours.)

Comment: people ssh to other operating systems from their macs.  and non-macs use Shift Insert alot.  The OP did non ask "how do I paste on a mac" he said exactly "how to do shift+insert on mac keyboard"

Comment: I still disagree @Wayne, given the very short question and it _only_ being tagged `mac`. And **of course** other answers are valid too. See the comments above. (In which "Shift+Enter" should have read "Shift+Insert".) Bummer "some user" never posted their solution, great that you now posted yours 13 years later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/262770/151785

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 104 = Insert"
```

Now `Fn` `Enter` (which on a mac sends `KP_Enter` (keycode 104)) sends `Insert`, so `Shift` `Fn` `Enter` sends our beloved `Shift` `Insert`!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up working Ctrl/Shift+Insert/Delete shortcuts for Copy, Cut and Paste using Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: Its starting to look like spam now. Please read the help on self promotion

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to make it look like spam. Was just excited about the solution and wanted to post it as an answer to multiple questions.